# Install makefile on Heroku application

Tags: heroku

I have a Rails application running on Heroku. My application calls a CLI tool (on my local machine) that was installed via Makefile. I need this Makefile installed on my Heroku application so that it's available to all my application instances.

How can I have heroku install this makefile on deploy? I'm able to accomplish this on CircleCI by passing it some pre-deploy arguments in their config file:

`cd vendor/liblouis ; ./configure ; make ; sudo make install`

Does Heroku offer something similar?
I reached out to their support, but they pointed me to some buildpack for makefiles. This won't work (I think) because it wont allows me to run ./configure

Answer (score 1):

I think it is doable, but will require some work and it will be hard to give you straightforward solution. You should definitely use a buildpack and compile everything during build phase. I found [this buildpack](https://github.com/colonyamerican/heroku-buildpack-make). I don't know if this is a recommended one, but it can be a good starting point.

It is true that it won't run `configure`, but you can actually fork it and modify it in a way that you want. You just need to be smart about configuring all the paths. Installing in `/usr/bin` or something like that won't work. Also you should probably use `make install` instead of `sudo make install`.

Inside this buildpack you have access to 3 directories: build, cache and env. You need to install your executable or library in build directory.

I believe you can practice on one-off dyno before modifying this buildpack. Just run `heroku run bash` and try to compile your Makefile.

Comment: I can get this working on a dyno `heroku run bash`, and the application works. I put together a build pack with the same commands, and I can see that during deploy it installs correctly. When I `heroku run bash` and try to launch the CLI tool, it says that it's missing the shared library. I don't know how to get each instance to link to the shared library...

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to get this working, but had to create my own custom buildpack. Buildpacks are a lot simpler than I thought, but I forked an existing one and edited it to work for my case. I stored my makefiles in the `vendor` directory of my application.

In the buildpack, I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# bin/compile <build-dir> <cache-dir>

set -e
set -o pipefail

BUILD_DIR=$1
CACHE_DIR=$2

function indent() {
  c='s/^/       /'
  case $(uname) in
    Darwin) sed -l "$c";;
    *)      sed -u "$c";;
  esac
}

cd $BUILD_DIR/vendor/liblouis

# autoreconfig
echo "-----> Running autoreconfig"
  autoreconf -f -i  2>&1 | indent

# configure
if [ -f configure ]; then
  echo "-----> Configuring"
  ./configure --prefix=$BUILD_DIR/vendor/liblouis-exec 2>&1 | indent
fi

# make
echo "-----> Compiling with Make"
make 2>&1 | indent

# make install
echo "-----> Installing with Make"
make install 2>&1 | indent
```

I pushed the buildpack to my own repo, and then added the buildpack to my heroku application with
`heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/KidA001/heroku-buildpack-c`

I also had to create a `.profile` file in the root directory of my application add add a link to a file which needed to be linked to a shared library

**.profile**

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/vendor/liblouis-exec/lib
```

Now I can call this CLI tool that was installed in this buildpack, and it's available on all of my app instances on heroku.